# Magento 2 Checkout address Add field with File type

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, customer-attribute, customer-address, custom-field

I want to add a field with File input type in checkout page.

**Ex. A field for upload resume from checkout page which can be downloadable from admin side.**

Is there any options to add this kind of field?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I have example module for input filed, not for uploading file

Comment: I know about input fields but I want to add file input @Ramesh

Comment: Sorry @Ronak i did't tried that, can you please provide any solution for this issue:  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180066/magento-2-adding-multiple-items-to-cart-at-one-time